# Gearman with libmysql

Tags: mysql, gearman

I have built gearman with libmysql.

```
 * CPP Flags:                  -fvisibility=hidden
   * LIBS:
   * LDFLAGS Flags:
   * Assertions enabled:        no
   * Debug enabled:             no
   * Warnings as failure:       no
   * Building with libsqlite3   no
   * Building with libdrizzle   yes
   * Building with libmemcached yes
   * Building with libpq        no
   * Building with tokyocabinet no
   * Building with libmysql     yes
```

Inside my gearmand.conf file, I added the following, referring to other documentation:

```
PARAMS="--queue-type=mysql \
--mysql-host=localhost \
--mysql-port=3306 \
--mysql-user=root \
--mysql-db=deliver \
--mysql-table=gearman"
```

I can connect to my local mysql with root and there is a db called "deliver". When I run the gearmand server, and add new jobs and workers, I don't see table "gearman" created.

The processes seem to to run just fine. I have tried the verbose mode of logging and checking gearmand.log file, but there is nothing related to mysql. Where should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a user 'gearman' for mysql and give permission for deliver database. And restart everything gearmand and mysql